# How to get EditText (vertical line) animation without keyboard

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

How to get EditText (vertical line) animation without keyboard?

The edittext keyboard should not appear when the activity starts, but the write animation should start.

[image]

Comment: I start with a lame question, why do you want that? What would this line (cursor) communicate to the user?

Comment: just because I've seen it in a lot of programs :)

Comment: Could you link us to an Android app that has it?

Comment: Such animations are there first and foremost to communicate a certain state. In this case, that the EditText is focussed and the user can type. Since this is not the case, this animation would only be distractive and confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You should request focus for the EditText, then hide the keyboard. I don't think there's any EditText class function to achieve this.

```
editText.requestFocus();
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

in your activity's onCreate.

This should leave the cursor in the EditText visible, but hide the keyboard. When the user clicks into the EditText, the keyboard appears as normal.